# Lxde - desktop file for opening files in lxterminal

Tags: 12.10, lxde, .desktop, lxterminal

I have a .desktop file in .local/share/applications for opening text files in vim (console version). This works perfectly in gnome, unity. In Lxde it fails. I tried using lxterminal in place of gnome-terminal. It opens copy of the file and not the file itself (when saving, it asks if I want to replace the original file).

What is wrong? How can I set it right?

And here is the .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Vim Text Editor (Console)
Comment=Edit text files in a console using Vim
# Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=yaadyaa --maximize --execute bash -c "vim %u"
Exec=lxterminal -e vim "%u"
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/vim.svg
Categories=Application;Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
NoDisplay=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Having **Terminal=true** is probably what breaks it. That tells the OS to open *a terminal* with the command in the Exec line. So set Terminal to false, and make sure you have the command string for lxterminal [correctly formatted](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/). Below is my desktop file for opening files in nano, another console text-editor.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Nano Text Editor (Console)
Comment=Edit text files in a console using Nano
Exec=lxterminal -t Nano --command=/usr/bin/nano\ "%f"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=lxterminal
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```